# Spring equivalent of EJB Stateless bean

Tags: spring, ejb, javabeans, stateless

In EJB because of performance reasons beans should be stateless, then application server can maintain pool of beans and assign them to requesting clients.

What is Spring equivalent for such type of beans? In Spring we've got other scopes of beans: singleton, prototype, request, session, global session.

Comment: unless you have a good reason use the default scope - singleton, which is indeed stateless

Comment: "In EJB because of performance reasons beans should be stateless" - I wouldn't exactly put it like that. If you need stateful or singleton beans, then that's what you need. However, if you don't need e.g. state -then- it's a waste to use stateful beans and you should stick to stateless ones.

Comment: @ArjanTijms That's what I wanted to say :)

Comment: @NimChimpsky but request scope can be also concerned as stateless? I've found in some tutorials that e.g. beans for REST should be request scope?

Comment: Anything defined as RESTful should be stateless : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Constraints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Spring bean should be implemented statelessly as a singleton.  Do not introduce state into a singleton bean. There is no real benefit from pooling in such an architecture.

Comment: But if there is no real benefit of pooling, why EJB have stateless beans at all?

Comment: Because the "state" in stateless is meant from clients point of view (e.g. there is no relation between the calling client and its serving bean and each call can be served by different beans). Stateless bean can hold other resources which are expansive to create, like DB connections for example. Therefore it really is worth pooling from obvious reasons.